# loop through each line in a json file and filter the result

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Hi I have a json file that contains something as below. I want to write a code to look through each line in the file and filter out the items that is of "emoji": "1" and output the result to another json file.

Input

```
{"o": [{"item": {"emoji": "0"}}]}
{"p": [{"item": {"emoji": "1"}}]}
{"q": [{"item": {"emoji": "1"}}]}
{"r": [{"item": {"emoji": "0"}}]}
```

Output

```
{"p": [{"item": {"emoji": "1"}}]}
{"q": [{"item": {"emoji": "1"}}]}
```

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `dataframe` tag, which you have used

Comment: What did you try and what is the problem? share the code please.

Comment: This is not a json file, but a file containing json lines... Read the file line by line, convert the line into a dict(say `data`) with `json.loads` and then examine `data.values[0]` or more precisely `data.values[0]['item']['emoji']`...

Comment: ```grep -hnr -A2 -B2 --no-group-separator "{\"emoji\"\: \"1\"\}" /input.json > output.json```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to work with the structure of your json data, would be to iterate over all lines in the file and check if a specific string is in the line:

```
filtered_json = []
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if '"emoji": "1"' in line:
            filtered_json.append(line)
```

this is of course a bit sloppy but will be a quick fix.

you can now write the `filtered_json` with:

```
with open('new_data.json', 'w') as file:
    new_data = '\n'.join(filtered_json)
    file.write(new_data)
```

---

The more complicated way of working with your json data would be using the `json` package:

```
import json
filtered_json = []
with open('data', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        j = json.loads(line)
        if int(j[list(j.keys())[0]][0]['item']['emoji']) == 1:
             filtered_json.append(j)
```

this is pretty bad and writing data to a file is going to be a weird as well.

---

we can make this a lot better by altering your json data, into actual json format:

old data.json:

```
{"q": [{"item": {"emoji": "1"}}]}
{"r": [{"item": {"emoji": "0"}}]}
```

new data.json:

```
{
    "r": {"item": {"emoji": 0}},
    "q": {"item": {"emoji": 1}}
}
```

We can now use this new data.json file in a simpler way by working with the `json` package:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    j = json.load(file)
    filtered_json = {}
    for key in j.keys():
        if j[key]['item']['emoji'] == 1:
            filtered_json[key] = j[key]
```

By altering the json file we achieved a much simpler code. We can even use a dict comprehension like this:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    j = json.load(file)
    filtered_data = {k: v for k, v in j.items() if v['item']['emoji'] == 1}
```

which is probably the most pythonic way of doing this

---

You can write the `filtered_json` here by just calling:

```
with open('new_data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(filtered_json, file)
```